# Docker container_linux.go:247. Что за ошибка и почему она вылетает?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Выполняю команду `winpty docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash`

При этом постоянно вылетает эта ошибка:

```
C:/Program Files/Docker/Docker/Resources/bin/docker.exe: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused 
"exec: \"C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe\": stat C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe: no such file or directory".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что я запускал команду в консоли Git Bash, а нужно было в обычной Widnows Powershell консоли.

и без приставки `winpty`

По итогу команда такая: `docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash`